# Is the following rv integrable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the probability space $((0,1],\mathcal{B}((0,1]),\lambda|_{(0,1]})$ and define $$X_n(\omega) := \frac{1}{\omega} 1_{\big(0, \frac{1}{n}\big]}(\omega).$$

I am told that this R.V. is not integrable. Why is this the case? I know that for a R.V. to be integrable in$L^1$, it must have finite expectation. But I can not see why $E[X_n(w)]=\infty$.

Comment: Because $\int_0^{1\over n} {1 \over t} dt = \infty$.

Comment: So the lebesegue measure us actually $dP(w)=dw$?

Comment: Hmmmm, yes. What did you think it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, our probability measure here is $\lambda\vert_{(0,1]}$ so $\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega) = \mathsf d\omega$ and 
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\ \mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega) 
= \int_{(0,1/n]} \frac1\omega\ \mathsf d\omega = +\infty,
$$
so $X$ is not integrable.